# extended dll version number in windows 7

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-7

I am trying to verify my latest dll was deployed to test environment.

When I right click on the dll --> properties and then details tab, the product version looks like below.

[image]

However, from the company's test environment diagnostic page version number look like: 1.6.0.28117

How can I see this extended dll version number in windows 7?

Comment: What does the file version look like? (The product version sometimes is different - the missing piece of information is the build number, and that's really not part of the product version. The version number is usually `major.minor.release.build`, and the build isn't pertinent to the product version; it's only signficant at the file level.)

Comment: Is this a dll you wrote and deployed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This windows explorer extension did the trick for me.

http://powerext.codeplex.com/